# Lightning Experience Rollout Specialist step 7

Tags: lightning

Getting an error as,

Challenge Not yet complete... here's what's wrong: 
John Wiseman must be subscribed to receive the Opportunities Pipeline report every Monday at 8 am.

Where i have schedule "Opportunities Pipeline" report at 8:00 AM but still getting this error.Got Stuck in this challenge, please help me.

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Lightning has a new way to schedule reports. Go to the report, click the dropdown beside edit and click subscribe. You can then schedule the report much like you did in Classic.